# Call Alert Function from within Fancybox Popup Window - iFrame and Same Origin Policy

Tags: javascript, fancybox, alert, same-origin-policy

I Have a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nicorellius/4vQ9S/

The alert fires on show start and show over and close, but binding to the button click is eluding me.

I have a fancybox popup that works.  It's a form:

The HTML is a simple table:

```
<form id="my-form" method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="name">Name</label></td>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The link that triggers fancybox:

```
<a class="fancy-popup" href="test.html" data-fancybox-type="iframe">
```

I have a simple script that calls some functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function before_show() {
        alert("fancybox before show");
    }

    function after_show() {
        alert("fancybox after show");
    }

    function on_close() {
        alert("fancybox after close");
    }

    function alert_me() {
        $.fancybox.inner.find('iframe').contents().find('input.click-me').click(function() {
            alert("fancybox has been foiled!!!");
        });
    }

    $(".fancy-popup").fancybox({
        openSpeed     :    'slow',
        openEffect    :    'fade',
        minWidth      :    '200',
        minHeight     :    '100',
        maxWidth      :    '400',
        maxHeight     :    '150',
        scrolling     :    'no',
        beforeShow    :    before_show,
        afterShow     :    after_show,
        afterClose    :    on_close,
        //afterShow     :    alert_me
    });
});
```

I'm realizing that I cannot do this within the iFrame, because of the same origin policy.  I can't figure out for the life of me how to get this to work.

**NOTE**

Please note that the question has changed since its inception, so the answer below referring to validation is not applicable.

Comment: You can add your alert, you can use AJAX too, to your form with `XHR` and you even can use iframe in you fancybox (not recomended, but you can). Did you try to bind your code with some of many `form validator` plugins from jquery?

Comment: I haven't tried tried these methods yet, as I was hoping to get it to work this way.  But now that it seems like it's harder to get working than I originally thought, I may seek other methods.  I will most likely go to the jQuery form validator plugins.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of pain, I decided to rework this without using an iFrame.  I thought the iFrame was the best way to go but then realized I was wrong, at least at my current level of understanding.  However, with this method, I can successfully call the alert from the fancyBox popup:

http://jsfiddle.net/nicorellius/d4KVs/

I think I can use my existing validation here too.

Here is HTML that changed:

```
<a href="#test" class="fancy-popup">fancy link</a>
```

I put the HTML in one place and referenced it using existing fancyBox techniques.

I didn't give up all the way, however.  I kept on fiddling with it and found a solution using the iFrame.  Not sure exactly what I did, but I set up original plan, and used the script:

```
    function alert_me() {
        $.fancybox.inner.find('iframe').contents().find(
            'input.click-me').click(function() {
                alert("fancybox has been foiled!!!");
        });
    }
```

and now the alert box pops up within the iFrame fancyBox.

The thing is with this solution is:  it may be limited to the same domain I'm on, so in production it probably wont work.  I ran a quick test and it seems to work cross domain but I have a feeling it'll cause me trouble in the future...